# Combining two mapStateToProps React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having some problems with MapStateToProps function with React.
I need to define state in const but no success, because I have one more (settings) to define in it.

Code looks like this.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ settings }) => {
  const { locale, navCollapsed } = settings;
  return { locale, navCollapsed }
};
```

Which works, but I need to add

```
 authenticated: state.auth.token !== null
```

in return statement, but in order to work it needs to look like.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
```

So my question is how to combine this two mapStateToProps.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ settings }) => {
  const { locale, navCollapsed } = settings;
  return { locale, navCollapsed }
};
```

and this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { authenticated: state.auth.token !== null }
};
```

Comment: Can you give some sample data for the settings object? And some sample data showing what you expect after the map would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `mapStateToProps` isn't react stuff, it's redux stuff. In order to get it working, you just need to follow the `state` example, because that's the official/basic interface.

```
  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
      authenticated: state.auth.token !== null,
      locale: state.settings.locale
    }
  }
```

The reason you had this question is that you thought `state` and `{ settings }` is different, but actually they are the same thing in your examples. Just search destructure of javascript then.